# What is the best way to migrate the code from the SubVersion (SVN) repository into the TFS?

Tags: svn, tfs, migration, tortoisesvn

We have lot of code in the SVN which has to be migrated into TFS. What is the best way to go ahead with this.

I beleive that downloading all data from SVN to harddrive and then uploading from the harddrive to TFS will result in loss of history data, so is there a better way that preserves the code as well as versioning/history?

Comment: Have a look at this blog http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2013/08/migrate-svn-to-tfs-its-free/

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to preserve history than you can simply check-in the latest sources to TFS. If you want to preserve history, there is a tool Timely Migration that you can use

http://timelymigration.com/svn-to-tfs.aspx